# Optimize the filling of M baskets that have an x count limit with n balls with basket preference

Tags: statistics, optimization

Think of this problem as an optimization problem. The platform has $M$ Baskets. Each Basket can hold up to $X$ items in it. This exercise is to fill all Baskets with as many balls as possible... But here's the caveat: the balls have predetermined preference for all baskets.

For example - say we have two baskets that fit two balls.Also we have five balls. The first three balls have a preference of $\{1,2\}$ and the two last balls have $\{2,1\}$.
Iterating randomly we can place in basket:
\begin{split}
1 \{\text{ball } 1&,\text{ball }2\}\\
2 \{\text{ball }4&,\text{ball }5\}
\end{split}
and ball $3$ is out of luck and remains in the inventory.

I hope I articulated this problem good enough for your help. The goal is to program this to a set-based solution (SQL server) but I would like to pin down the mathematical logic first.

Comment: What do you mean by preference ? Is it random, with more chance to go in basket 1 for instance, or is it that the ball is gonna go in basket 1 every time it has a chance to? Also is there some sort of order for the balls ?

Comment: Hi Daniel 
Preference is pre-labeled. That means, by definition, ball a for example should go to basked 1 if basked 1 is full then the next choice should be 5 if 5 is full then basked n ....
Each ball can be defined as a set ball n ={1,5,7,n} 
Does that make sense ?
Thanks 
Eddy

Comment: Yes. My second question was that from your example, it seems that balls 4 and 5 are placed in baskets before ball 3. How is this order determined ?

Comment: The order is completely random - therefore optimization should weigh in to guide the algorithm to optimize the population. That is, grant the first choice to as many balls as possible, then the second choice to as many balls as possible ...

Comment: Ok and the distribution of the preference for each ball is completely random ? Uniform or anything ?

Comment: Anyway for this kind of problem the usual approach is to create a regret function and work from it. Possibly some dynamic optimization could be useful.

Comment: anything would work for distribution preference. I'll give the regret theory a shot - and see what comes out it! thanks